# C# GRPC Reference existing object

Tags: c#, grpc

Im completely new in using GRPC. I have and question regarding setting up the .proto file.
In my existing solution i have forexample this class:

```
    public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string? Type {get; set;}
}
```

The Car class is placed in a Core project, since it's used by other logic around the solution. But if i like to return in my GRPC Server, is it really necessary to define it in the .proto file again ala this:

```
message CarReply {
  int32 Id = 1;
  string Brand = 2;
  string Type = 3;
}
```

What i liked was an reference to my Car() class. Is this not possible?

Comment: you could mark Car as partial, and have the member defined in *.proto file and have logic in *.cs file. For this to work Car and CarReply need to have the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use vanilla "contract first" protobuf, then yes: you need to use a schema and the generated type - it is the generated type that knows how to perform the serialization.

However! There may be an alternative; protobuf-net (and protobuf-net.Grpc) provide an independent implementation of protobuf that supports "code first" usage, which allows you to use your existing type model.

The *easiest* way to do this with protobuf-net is to annotate your model (using either protobuf-net's attributes, or the framework data-contract attributes - the first option giving more control); for example:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class Car
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string? Type {get; set;}
}
```

It *is* also possible to configure everything at runtime, but that's a bit harder.

This can also be used fully with gRPC, using interfaces to define the service contract; [full guidance is here](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/gettingstarted)